# Proper way to CFRelease CFMutableArrayRef contents

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, core-foundation

I am using CFMutableArrayRef in my code. There I am adding several CFTypeRef elements.

When I am done using the array, do I need to call `CFArrayRemoveAllValues(myArray);` before actually releasing the array or simply calling to `CFRelease(myArray);` will deallocate array contents as well?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `CFRelease` is all you need to do, assuming the objects contained in the array are managed appropriately.

`CFArray` is open-source and you can see the implementation yourself at https://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-1153.18/CFArray.c.auto.html (look for `__CFArrayDeallocate`  and `__CFArrayReleaseValues`).

`CFArray` is toll-free bridged with `NSArray` so in Objective-C it's rarely necessary to use `CFArray` directly.